# df.col.str.contains('somestr') doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

Faced very weird thing - I need to drop rows containing '|' symbol in my df, but when I use `.loc` method the df stays the same, even though if I filter it by other character, f.e. 'a', it works.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['aaa', 'bbb | aaa', 'ccc'], 'B':['abababa', 'a | b', 'abab | abab']})
colA = 'A'
```

```py
display(df.loc[df[colA].str.contains('|')])
```

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | aaa | abababa |
| 1 | bbb | aaa | a | b |
| 2 | ccc | abab | abab |

```py
 display(df.loc[df['A'].str.contains('|')]
```

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | aaa | abababa |
| 1 | bbb | aaa | a | b |
| 2 | ccc | abab | abab |

```py
display(df.loc[df['A'].str.contains('a')])
```

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | aaa | abababa |
| 1 | bbb | aaa | a | b |

Does anyone know how can I bypass it?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), the `regex` argument defaults to `True`, so it is interpreting the pipe character as a disjunction operator, not a literal pipe.

Simply set `regex=False` to fix this:

```
>>> print(df.loc[df['A'].str.contains('|', regex=False)])
           A      B
1  bbb | aaa  a | b
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will be aware of the regex from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the regex

```
display(df.loc[df['A'].str.contains(r'\|', regex=True)])
display(df.loc[df['A'].str.contains(r'a', regex=True)])
```

```
            A       B
1   bbb | aaa   a | b

            A       B
0   aaa       abababa
1   bbb | aaa   a | b
```